# Что такое фадж?

Tags: значение-слов

Читаю книгу Султана Шамши Путешествие Ибн-Фадлана на реку Итиль и встретил такое предложение:

> Женщины там не закры­ваются  ни  от  мужчин,  ни  от  посторонних,  тело  тоже  нескрывают  ни  от  кого  из  людей.  И  действительно,  как-то произошел с нами такой случай: когда мы остановились у одного из местных жителей и уселись побеседовать,  жена хозяина  была  с  нами.  И  вот  во  время  разговора  она  от­крыла  свой  **«фадж»**  и,  нисколько  нас  не  стесняясь,  по­чесалась  там.  Мы  от  стыда  закрыли  лица  и  произнесли: «Прости  нас,  Аллах!»  А  муж  ее  засмеялся  и  сказал  пе­реводчику:

Что, собственно, такое фадж?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

галина в общем правильно написала, но есть ошибки, я могу конкретно из словаря показать.

пропущена буква р:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farj
- https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%AC/
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%AC

не путать с утренней молитвой, с его временем, с событием его времени - рассветом:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajr
- https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%81%D8%AC%D8%B1/
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%AC%D8%B1

Answer (score 2):

> ...И называются эти пять ежедневных молитв фадж, зухр, аср, магриб и иша.
>
> ---

[**Фадж**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6)

У этого термина существуют и другие значения, см. [Фадж (значения)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

---

Из контекста ясно, что закавыченный фадж - слово-заменитель, эвфемизм.

> ...— Скажи им: хотя она и открывается в вашем присутствии и вы видите
>   ее, но она охраняет себя так, что никого туда не допустит. Это все же
>   лучше, чем если бы она закрывалась, и вместе с тем уступала себя
>   кому-то.
>
> Блуд им вообще не известен. Но если все же кого-либо уличат в этом,
>   разрывают на две части: сгибают деревья друг к другу и человека
>   привязывают к его веткам. Потом одновременно отпускают оба дерева — и
>   человека разрывает на части.

Что именно зачесалось, не уточнено, но область чесания обозначена - промежность. "Своё хозяйство" почесала муслимка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Я ничего не поняла из принятого ответа @qdinar: ни **что** открыла и почесала жена хозяина, ни **куда** надо было, по его мнению, поставить пропущенную букву **р**. Честное слово.
2. Так получилось, что сейчас я читаю Э. Тополя, "Любожид, или Русская дива". И там вот что "попалось".

*Так значит, прав был Ахмед ибн Фадлан, когда писал: «…так прекрасны русские девушки и **так сильны их фарджи**, что ничто не может оторвать мужчину от сочетания с ними».*

*А другой анонимный арабский путешественник объяснил этот феномен еще точнее: **«Фарджа** русской девушки подобна сластолюбивому питону, который затягивает мужчину в себя с силой быка. Я никогда не испытывал ничего подобного ни с одной арабской женщиной в гаремах моей страны».*

*...застежка держала, оказывается, всю ее одежду, которая разом рухнула теперь на ковер шатра, открыв перед ним ее невозможно белое тело, стройное, как камыш или стилет, с атласной кожей, <…> тонкими золотыми браслетами на руках и ногах и зелеными гривнами на шее. Скорее инстинктивным, чем обдуманным жестом, она тут же прикрыла руками грудь и **золотой пух свой фарджи.***

3. Тут же вспомнилась "Тысяча и одна ночь".

*Она стала играть в воде и плескалась и плевалась и, набрав воды в рот, обрызгала носильщика, а потом она вымыла свои члены и то, что между бедрами и, выйдя из воды, бросилась носильщику на колени и сказала: «О господин мой, о мой любимый, как называется вот это?» — и показала на свой **фардж.***

Получается, что фардж (или фарджа) — это то, что находится у женщины внизу живота (лобок) и во внутренней части бедер.